# Simplyfying the use of '?:' conditional operator

Tags: javascript, optimization, for-loop, conditional-operator

I have a loop written like so

```
for( i = (count>=0)?1:-1;(count>=0)?i<=count:i>=count;(count>=0)?i++:i--){
           do_something_with( i )
        }
```

As you can see I am using the `?` operator 3 time in the loop initialization .

Is there any way to simplify this ? 
Currently the cpu has to compute a minimum of 2 extra decisions and a max of 3 extra
for each and every iteration. I am trying to reduce this .

Ps : I am trying to avoid using `if` statements .

Currently I am using javascript  as a language

Comment: Why avoid if statements?

Comment: Well I am try to make the number of lines less thats why

Comment: "I am try to make the number of lines less" - why ??? This is in general a bad idea unless you are getting rid of redundancy.

Comment: Why so few lines of code? Depending on the language, the number of lines of code won't matter, it'll all be optimized.

Comment: @PaulR I know that its not such a great idea but I am trying out a few challenges.

Comment: By the way Any one have a better title for this question please update it

Comment: Why the -1 , Please have the courtesy to Leave a comment who ever downvoted

Comment: I down-voted it earlier because the question didn't even have an appropriate language tag and in general was unclear - I have now removed the comment about the need for a language tag but the down-vote gets locked in after a certain time.

Comment: Aah !!!, Its really hard for me to choose the answer to accept. Both seem to be equally good

Comment: When you have two or more equally good answers then the usual practice is to accept the one that was posted first

Comment: @PaulR : True I agree , but both have put in some effort to update their answers to correct it . I feel that its really unfair to accept one over the other even choosing based on votes seems unfair . May be I'll wait 2 - 3 days and see what he community thinks

Comment: Well upvote both, accept one, and move on...

Comment: Why the down vote Again ? Whats wrong with this Question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the decision once at the start of the loop, and use the `!=` operator for the comparison:

```
for (var dir = count >= 0 ? 1 : -1, i = dir; i != count + dir; i += dir){
  do_something_with(i);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2Z369/

Comment: The method seems really nice , But I need it to iterate till the value count , ie if count is 5 `i` has to loop till 5

Comment: @GautamK: I see. Then you compare to `count + dir`. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Form your logic within the body of the loop like:

```
// reverse count if required
int fixedCount = count >= 0 ? count : 0 - count;
for (i = 1; i <= fixedCount; i++)
{
    // reverse i if required
    int fixedIndex = count >= 0 ? i : 0 - i;

    do_something(fixedIndex);
}
```

Comment: -1, if `count < 0` this loop will only run once or maybe not at all, depending on the language.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - Good catch, reversed the count as well, still 2 checks rather than 3

Comment: Removed -1. It now works, but perhaps a better choice than `?:` to assign fixedCount would be `Math.abs(count)`.

Comment: That's arguable, for one,the logic is more consistent now with the fixedIndex determination. A matter of preference and more likely language independent